# Lesson plan - java JApplet

Tags: java, swing, applet, jtable, japplet

I write a lesson plan/timetable.
I just want to make like this:

[image]

On the right of the table it will be form to add a lesson.
Do you think it would be best to use the control JTable?

Comment: Generally yes. You might want to investigate column/row spanning. [This](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JTableExamples4.html) might help

Answer (score 1):

> On the right of the table it will be form to add a lesson. Do you
>   think it would be best to use the control JTable?

- JTable isn't proper JComponents for timetable, sheduler
- use JPanel layed by SpringLayout, GridBagLayout, custom TableLayout
- use AbsoluteLayout in the case that any of elements will be expansible, or draggable